# CORS ERROR http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_FAILED 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I'm getting cors error

```
const api = getAPI(); // HERE's ERROR

function getAPI() {
    return (fetch('http://localhost:3000')); // returns a promise
}
```

```
register.html:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
register.js:103 GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_FAILED 200
getAPI @ register.js:103
register @ register.js:97
register.js:103   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getAPI (register.js:103)
    at HTMLButtonElement.register (register.js:97)
```

Here's my main app, app.js (api)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const mysqlConObj = require('./config/mysql.js')
const db = mysqlConObj.init()
const cors = require('cors');
mysqlConObj.open(db)
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('MyAPIName'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server Running. . .'))
app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true})); // CORS SETUP
```

Also, this doesn't work. (Both of

```
app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true}));
```

and

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Set-Cookie, Cookie"); // select only the ones you need
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

    next();
});
```

doesn't work.)

I already do cors setup.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

I imported CORS well.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Your server is running at localhost:3000 not the front-end app.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I know that. so what do you want to say?

Comment: If you want quick fix just allow it everywhere with app.use(cors())

Comment: Of course, ```app.use(cors());``` occurs same error.

Comment: Can you try sending request with Postman?

Comment: Okay but I won't use postman but i'll try with it

Comment: Umm sorry It's very difficult to use postman